# GROUP BY one column, while sorting by another in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

How can I `GROUP BY` one column, while sorting *only* by another.

I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT dbId,retreivalTime 
    FROM FileItems 
    WHERE sourceSite='something' 
    GROUP BY seriesName 
    ORDER BY retreivalTime DESC 
    LIMIT 100 
    OFFSET 0;
```

I want to select the *last* /n/ items from FileItems, in descending order, with the rows filtered by `DISTINCT` values of `seriesName`. The above query errors out `ERROR:  column "fileitems.dbid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I need the `dbid` value in order to then take the output of this query, and `JOIN` it on the source table to get the rest of the columns I wasn.

Note this is basically the gestalt of the below question, with a lot of the extraneous details removed for clarity.

---

## Original question

I have a system I'm migrating from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL, because I've largely outgrown sqlite:

```
    SELECT
            d.dbId,
            d.dlState,
            d.sourceSite,
        [snip a bunch of rows]
            d.note

    FROM FileItems AS d
        JOIN
            ( SELECT dbId
                FROM FileItems
                WHERE sourceSite='{something}'
                GROUP BY seriesName
                ORDER BY MAX(retreivalTime) DESC
                LIMIT 100
                OFFSET 0
            ) AS di
            ON  di.dbId = d.dbId
    ORDER BY d.retreivalTime DESC;
```

Basically, I want to select the *last* n `DISTINCT` items in the database, where the distinct constraint is on one column, and the sorting order is on a different column.

Unfortunately, the above query, while it works fine in sqlite, errors out in PostgreSQL with the error  `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "fileitems.dbid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

Unfortunately, while adding `dbId` to the GROUP BY clause fixes the issue (e.g. `GROUP BY seriesName,dbId`), it means the distinct filtering on the query results no longer work, since `dbid` is the database primary key, and as such all values are distinct.

From reading the [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), there is `SELECT DISTINCT ON ({nnn})`, but that requires that the returned results be sorted by `{nnn}`.

Therefore, to do what I'd want via `SELECT DISTINCT ON`, I'd have to query for all `DISTINCT {nnn}` and their `MAX(retreivalTime)`, sort *again* by `retreivalTime` rather then `{nnn}`, then take the largest 100 and query using those against the table to get the rest of the rows,  which I'd like to avoid, as the database has ~175K rows and ~14K distinct values in the `seriesName` column, I only want the latest 100, and this query is somewhat performance critical (I need query times < 1/2 second).

My naive assumption here is basically the DB needs to just iterate over each row in descending order of `retreivalTime`, and simply stop once it's seen `LIMIT` items, so a full table query is non-ideal, but I don't pretend to really understand how the database system optimizes internally, and I may be approaching this completely wrong.

FWIW, I *do* occasionally use different `OFFSET` values, but long query times for cases where offset > ~500 is completely acceptable. Basically, `OFFSET` is a crappy paging mechanism that lets me get away without needing to dedicate scrolling cursors to each connection, and I'll probably revisit it at some point.

---

Ref - [Question I asked a month ago that lead to this query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72358/improving-group-by-query-performance-in-sqlite3).

---

Ok, more notes:

```
    SELECT
            d.dbId,
            d.dlState,
            d.sourceSite,
        [snip a bunch of rows]
            d.note

    FROM FileItems AS d
        JOIN
            ( SELECT seriesName, MAX(retreivalTime) AS max_retreivalTime
                FROM FileItems
                WHERE sourceSite='{something}'
                GROUP BY seriesName
                ORDER BY max_retreivalTime DESC
                LIMIT %s
                OFFSET %s
            ) AS di
            ON  di.seriesName = d.seriesName AND di.max_retreivalTime = d.retreivalTime
    ORDER BY d.retreivalTime DESC;
```

Works correctly for the query as described, but if I *remove* the `GROUP BY` clause, it fails (it's optional in my application).

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "FileItems.seriesname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I think I'm fundamentally not understanding how subqueries work in PostgreSQL. Where am I going wrong? I was under the impression that a subquery is basically just a inline function, where the results are just fed into the main query.

Comment: if anyone want to `group by + join rows data`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558509/concatenate-and-group-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Consistent rows

The important question which does not seem to be on your radar yet:
From each set of rows for the same `seriesName`, do you want the columns of *one* row, or just *any* values from multiple rows (which may or may not come from the same row)?

Your answer does the latter, you combine the maximum `dbid` with the maximum `retreivaltime`, which may come from a different row.

To get *consistent* rows, use `DISTINCT ON` and wrap it in a subquery to order the result differently:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (seriesName)
          dbid, seriesName, retreivaltime
   FROM   FileItems
   WHERE  sourceSite = 'mk' 
   ORDER  BY seriesName, retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST  -- latest retreivaltime
   ) sub
ORDER BY retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  100;
```

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Aside: should probably be `retrievalTime`, or better yet: `retrieval_time`. Unquoted mixed case identifiers are a common source of confusion in Postgres.

### Better Performance with rCTE

Since we are dealing with a big table here, we'd need a query that can use an index, which is not the case for the above query (except for `WHERE  sourceSite = 'mk'`)

On closer inspection, your problem seems to be a special case of a **loose index scan**. Postgres does not support loose index scans natively, but it can be emulated with a **recursive CTE**. There is a [code example for the simple case in the Postgres Wiki.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan)

See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894500/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Your case is more complex, though. I think I found a variant to make it work for you. Building on this index (without `WHERE  sourceSite = 'mk'`)

```
CREATE INDEX mi_special_full_idx ON MangaItems
(retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST, seriesName DESC NULLS LAST, dbid)
```

Or (with `WHERE  sourceSite = 'mk'`)

```
CREATE INDEX mi_special_granulated_idx ON MangaItems
(sourceSite, retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST, seriesName DESC NULLS LAST, dbid)
```

The first index can be used for both queries, but is not fully efficient with the additional `WHERE` condition. The second index is of very limited use for the first query. Since you have both variants of the query, consider creating ***both*** indexes.

I added `dbid` at the end to allow [*index-only* scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans).

This query with a recursive CTE makes use of the index. I tested with **Postgres 9.3** and it works for me: no sequential scan, all ***index-only*** scans:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT dbid, seriesName, retreivaltime, 1 AS rn, ARRAY[seriesName] AS arr
   FROM   MangaItems
   WHERE  sourceSite = 'mk'
   ORDER  BY retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST, seriesName DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i.dbid, i.seriesName, i.retreivaltime, c.rn + 1, c.arr || i.seriesName
   FROM   cte c
   ,      LATERAL (
      SELECT dbid, seriesName, retreivaltime
      FROM   MangaItems
      WHERE (retreivaltime, seriesName) < (c.retreivaltime, c.seriesName)
      AND    sourceSite = 'mk'  -- repeat condition!
      AND    seriesName <> ALL(c.arr)
      ORDER  BY retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST, seriesName DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1
      ) i
   WHERE  c.rn < 101
   )
SELECT dbid
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY rn;
```

You *need* to include `seriesName`  in `ORDER BY`, since `retreivaltime` is not unique. "Almost" unique is still *not* unique.

#### Explanation

- The non-recursive query starts with the latest row.
- The recursive query adds the next-latest row with a `seriesName` that's not in the list, yet etc., until we have 100 rows.
- Essential parts are the `JOIN` condition `(b.retreivaltime, b.seriesName) < (c.retreivaltime, c.seriesName)` and the `ORDER BY` clause `ORDER  BY retreivaltime DESC NULLS LAST, seriesName DESC NULLS LAST`. Both match the sort order of the index, which allows for the magic to happen.
- Collecting `seriesName` in an array to rule out duplicates. The cost for `b.seriesName <> ALL(c.foo_arr)` grows progressively with the number of rows, but for just 100 rows it is still cheap.
- Just returning `dbid` as clarified in the comments.

### Alternative with partial indexes:

We have been dealing with similar problems before. Here is a highly optimized complete solution based on partial indexes and a looping function:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500)

Probably the fastest way (except for a materialized view) if done right. But more complex.

### Materialized View

Since you do not have a lot of write operations and they are not performance-critical as stated in the comments (should be in the question), ***save*** the top n pre-computed rows in a materialized view and refresh it after relevant changes to the underlying table. Base your performance-critical queries on the materialized view instead.

- Could just be a "thin" mv of the latest 1000 `dbid` or so. In the query, join to the original table. For instance, if content is sometimes updated, but the top n rows can remain unchanged.
- Or a "fat" mv with whole rows to return. Faster, yet. Needs to be refreshed more often, obviously.

Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I've read the docs more, and now I understand the issue at least a bit better.

Basically, what's going on is there are multiple possible values for `dbid` as a result of the `GROUP BY seriesName` aggregation. With SQLite and MySQL, apparently the DB engine just choses one at random (which is absolutely fine in my application).

However, PostgreSQL is much more conservative, so rather then chose a random value, it throws an error.

A simple way to make this query work is to apply an *aggregation function* to the relevant value:

```
SELECT MAX(dbid) AS mdbid, seriesName, MAX(retreivaltime) AS mrt
    FROM MangaItems 
    WHERE sourceSite='mk' 
    GROUP BY seriesName
    ORDER BY mrt DESC 
    LIMIT 100 
    OFFSET 0;
```

This makes the query output fully qualified, and the query now works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I actually wound up using some procedural logic outside of the database to accomplish what I wanted to do.

Basically, 99% of the time, I want the *last* <strike>100</strike> 200 results. The query planner does not seem to optimize for this, and if the value of `OFFSET` is large, my procedural filter will be much slower.

Anyways, I used a named cursor to iterate over the rows in the database manually, retreiving the rows in groups of a few hundred. I then filter them for distinctness in my application code, and close the cursor immediately after I have accumulated the number of distinct results I wanted.

The `mako` code (basically python). Lots of debug statements remaining.

```
<%def name="fetchMangaItems(flags='', limit=100, offset=0, distinct=False, tableKey=None, seriesName=None)">
    <%
        if distinct and seriesName:
            raise ValueError("Cannot filter for distinct on a single series!")

        if flags:
            raise ValueError("TODO: Implement flag filtering!")

        whereStr, queryAdditionalArgs = buildWhereQuery(tableKey, None, seriesName=seriesName)
        params = tuple(queryAdditionalArgs)


        anonCur = sqlCon.cursor()
        anonCur.execute("BEGIN;")

        cur = sqlCon.cursor(name='test-cursor-1')
        cur.arraysize = 250
        query = '''

            SELECT
                    dbId,
                    dlState,
                    sourceSite,
                    sourceUrl,
                    retreivalTime,
                    sourceId,
                    seriesName,
                    fileName,
                    originName,
                    downloadPath,
                    flags,
                    tags,
                    note

            FROM MangaItems
            {query}
            ORDER BY retreivalTime DESC;'''.format(query=whereStr)

        start = time.time()
        print("time", start)
        print("Query = ", query)
        print("params = ", params)
        print("tableKey = ", tableKey)

        ret = cur.execute(query, params)
        print("Cursor ret = ", ret)
        # for item in cur:
        #   print("Row", item)

        seenItems = []
        rowsBuf = cur.fetchmany()

        rowsRead = 0

        while len(seenItems) < offset:
            if not rowsBuf:
                rowsBuf = cur.fetchmany()
            row = rowsBuf.pop(0)
            rowsRead += 1
            if row[6] not in seenItems or not distinct:
                seenItems.append(row[6])

        retRows = []

        while len(seenItems) < offset+limit:
            if not rowsBuf:
                rowsBuf = cur.fetchmany()
            row = rowsBuf.pop(0)
            rowsRead += 1
            if row[6] not in seenItems or not distinct:
                retRows.append(row)
                seenItems.append(row[6])

        cur.close()
        anonCur.execute("COMMIT;")

        print("duration", time.time()-start)
        print("Rows used", rowsRead)
        print("Query complete!")

        return retRows
    %>

</%def>
```

This currently retrieves the latest <strike>100</strike> 200 distinct series items in <strike>115</strike> ~80 milliseconds (lower time is when using a local connection, rather then a TCP socket), while processing approximately 1500 rows.

Come comments:

- Rows are read in chunks of 250.
- `buildWhereQuery` is my own dynamic query builder. Yes, this is a horrible idea. Yes, I know about SQLalchemy et al. I wrote my own because A. this is a personal project that I don't expect to ever use outside of my home LAN, and B. It's a **great** way to learn SQL.
- I may consider switching between the two query mechanisms as dependent on the value of offset. It looks like when offset > 1000 and I'm filtering for distinct items, this approach starts to exceed the time required for procedures like the ones in @ErwinBrandstetter's answer.
- @ErwinBrandstetter's answer is still a *much better* **general** solution. This is only better in one very specific case.
- I had to use two cursors, for some odd reason. You can't create a named cursor unless you're in a transaction, but you can't start a transaction without a cursor (note - this is with `autocommit` mode **off**). I have to instantiate a anonymous cursor, issue some SQL (just a `BEGIN`, here), create my named cursor, use it, close it, and finally commit with the anonymous cursor.
- This could probably be done entirely in PL/pgSQL, and the result would probably be even faster, but I know python much better.