# Finding the current prices for n Fuelstations at a certain point in time

Tags: postgresql, cte, performance, recursive, postgresql-performance

I have a Table where price information is stored in with approx 13 million rows stored in a PostgreSQL 9.5 database.

```
CREATE TABLE public.de_tt_priceinfo (
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('priceinfo_id_seq'::regclass),
  station_id character varying(60),
  received timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  e5 numeric(4,3),
  e10 numeric(4,3),
  diesel numeric(4,3),
  CONSTRAINT de_tt_priceinfo_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE INDEX de_tt_priceinfo_received_station_id_idx
  ON public.de_tt_priceinfo (received, station_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX index_station_id
  ON public.de_tt_priceinfo (station_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

From this table I need to extract the latest prices at a certain point in time with maximum performance, since I have to simulate 32 million commuters which query this table (not at once, but still).

I have a working query!

```
SELECT station_id, e5, e10, diesel, received FROM de_tt_priceinfo a 
WHERE a.received = (SELECT MAX(received) FROM de_tt_priceinfo b 
  WHERE a.station_id = b.station_id
  AND  received <= '2014-09-25 08:45:12'::TIMESTAMPTZ)
AND station_id IN('0C91A93A-a-b-c-d', '578C44BB-a-b-c-d', '6F2F48A8-a-b-c-d'
                , '9982BE74-a-b-c-d', 'A24C612B-a-b-c-d', 'BEC3EF55-a-b-c-d'
                , 'F5137488-a-b-c-d')
```

The performance of this Query is not usable. Execution time is varying around 900ms.
The result looks like this

```
0C91A93A-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 08:17:50.000000"
578C44BB-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 08:00:09.000000"
6F2F48A8-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 07:08:57.000000"
9982BE74-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 08:29:55.000000"
A24C612B-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 08:00:09.000000"
BEC3EF55-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 06:53:49.000000"
F5137488-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 07:44:55.000000"
```

So I searched around a little bit and found buzz words like recursive CTE, loose indexscan and some answers on DBA which seemed very close, but I could not modify them to my needs.

- [How do I efficiently get "the most recent corresponding row"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/how-do-i-efficiently-get-the-most-recent-corresponding-row)
- [GROUP BY one column, while sorting by another in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/group-by-one-column-while-sorting-by-another-in-postgresql)

If I understood right, a recursive CTE would be the quickest way to query the data I want.

What I got so far is this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT station_id, e5, e10, diesel, received
   FROM   de_tt_priceinfo
   WHERE  received <= '2014-09-25 08:45:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ
     AND station_id IN('0C91A93A-a-b-c-d', '578C44BB-a-b-c-d', '6F2F48A8-a-b-c-d'
                     , '9982BE74-a-b-c-d', 'A24C612B-a-b-c-d', 'BEC3EF55-a-b-c-d'
                     , 'F5137488-a-b-c-d')
   ORDER  BY station_id, received DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT 1  
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT u.station_id, u.e5, u.e10, u.diesel, u.received
   FROM   cte c
   JOIN de_tt_priceinfo u ON u.received > c.received   
   WHERE  u.received <= '2014-09-25 08:45:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ  -- repeat condition!
     AND u.station_id IN('0C91A93A-a-b-c-d', '578C44BB-a-b-c-d', '6F2F48A8-a-b-c-d'
                       , '9982BE74-a-b-c-d', 'A24C612B-a-b-c-d', 'BEC3EF55-a-b-c-d'
                       , 'F5137488-a-b-c-d')
   ORDER BY u.station_id, u.received DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1
   )
   )
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

But this just returns the following two lines:

```
0C91A93A-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 08:17:50.000000"
9982BE74-a-b-c-d, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, 1.xxx, "2014-09-25 08:29:55.000000"
```

Update:

- `SELECT Version();` PostgreSQL 9.5devel on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (Gentoo 4.8.3 p1.1, pie-0.5.9) 4.8.3, 64-bit
- EXPLAIN ANALYSE: http://explain.depesz.com/s/clrZ
- XEON 1231v3, 16 GB Ram, Samsung 840 PRO SSD
- Changes to the default postgresql.conf

```
# Connection
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 16

# Logging
log_destination = 'csvlog'
log_directory = 'pg_log'
logging_collector = on
log_filename = 'postgres-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 1GB
log_min_duration_statement = 500ms
#log_checkpoints = on
#log_connections = on
#log_disconnections = on
log_lock_waits = on
#log_temp_files = 0

# Memory
shared_buffers = 1GB
temp_buffers = 32MB
work_mem = 256MB
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 8GB

# Checkpoint ( When to write to disk )
wal_buffers = 16MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
checkpoint_timeout = 30min
checkpoint_segments = 32

random_page_cost = 1.1

# Import only!
#autovacuum = off
fsync = off
synchronous_commit = off
full_page_writes = off
```

Comment: For performance questions like this, the EXPLAIN output [as instructed here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) is instrumental.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter added the information requested

Comment: I assume the three `numeric(4,3)` columns `e5`, `e10` and `diesel` are prices with a precision of 0.1 Cent?

Comment: They are german fuel prices, which look like 1,319 Euro/l. The original data came from a mySQL database and was migrated to postgresql, thats why numeric(4,3) is used. To me its no difference to convert it to a different format, as long as I do not lose any precision. The table design is not mine, but was given so it is as it is.

Comment: Can they be NULL?

Comment: Yes they can e.g if a fuel stations does not have e10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Index

First and foremost, for your type of query this is the much better index:

```
CREATE INDEX de_tt_priceinfo_received_station_id_idx
  ON public.de_tt_priceinfo (station_id, received);  -- note the reversed order
```

Since the combination is supposed to be unique (I assume), I suggest a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(station_id, receved)` instead:

```
ALTER TABLE de_tt_priceinfo ADD CONSTRAINT de_tt_priceinfo_station_id_received
UNIQUE (station_id, received);
```

The index `index_station_id` is mostly superseded and can probably be dropped now.
The index `de_tt_priceinfo_received_station_id_idx` may still have its use.

Be sure to understand the logic behind all this:

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

#### Query

I would also consider the basic `DISTINCT ON` query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (station_id)
       station_id, e5, e10, diesel, received
FROM   de_tt_priceinfo
WHERE  received <= '2014-09-25 08:45:12'::TIMESTAMPTZ
AND    station_id = ANY ('{0C91A93A-a-b-c-d, 578C44BB-a-b-c-d, 6F2F48A8-a-b-c-d
                         , 9982BE74-a-b-c-d, A24C612B-a-b-c-d, BEC3EF55-a-b-c-d
                         , F5137488-a-b-c-d}'::varchar[])
ORDER BY station_id, received DESC;
```

But since you seem to have *a lot* of rows per station, that's not going to shine. Instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('0C91A93A-a-b-c-d'::varchar)
    , ('578C44BB-a-b-c-d')
    , ('6F2F48A8-a-b-c-d')
    , ('9982BE74-a-b-c-d')
    , ('A24C612B-a-b-c-d')
    , ('BEC3EF55-a-b-c-d')
    , ('F5137488-a-b-c-d')
   ) s(station_id)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT e5, e10, diesel, received
    FROM   de_tt_priceinfo
    WHERE  station_id = s.station_id
    AND    received <= '2014-09-25 08:45:12'::TIMESTAMPTZ
    ORDER  BY received DESC
    LIMIT  1
   )  p ON TRUE
```

This one should be dynamite in combination with above `UNIQUE` constraint (or an equivalent index).

Detailed explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

#### Table definition

For a table with millions of rows it pays to optimize storage while easily possible. Makes everything smaller and faster.

That's how I would design it:

```
CREATE TABLE station (
   station_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , station    text
 , CHECK (length(station) < 61) -- ?? optional, you decide 
);

CREATE TABLE priceinfo (
   priceinfo_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , station_id   integer NOT NULL REFERENCES station ON UPDATE CASCADE
 , received     timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
 , e5           integer  -- price in 0.1 Cent
 , e10          integer  -- price in 0.1 Cent
 , diesel       integer  -- price in 0.1 Cent
 , CONSTRAINT priceinfo_station_id_received UNIQUE (station_id, received)
);

CREATE INDEX priceinfo_received_idx ON public.priceinfo (received);
```

The row size in `priceinfo` would be **60 bytes** (24 heap tuple header + null bitmap; 32 bytes data; 4 bytes item identifier), as compared to **94 bytes** (24 + 66 + 4) in your original table. That's **assuming** 16-character string like in your example. Everything will be ~ 36 % smaller (or more?) and considerably faster.

The crucial index on `(station_id, received)` is down to **8 bytes** of data per index tuple instead of **32 bytes** or even much more (!) - each plus overhead. In addition, handling `integer` numbers for `station_id` is generally faster than text with a `COLLATION` on top of it.

Details:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Query would fetch `station_id` from `station` table first, which is cheap.

Prices are stored as `integer` numbers signifying 0.1 Cent. (**4 bytes** instead of **10 bytes** for your original `numeric(4,3)` Multiply with 0.1 to get Cent or 0.001 to get € for display. Very simple and fast.

#### `UUID`

The string in the error message looks considerably longer and actually like a regular [**`UUID`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) number:

```
871828b4-37e5-419c-b7a5-cdbe1e1c0148
```

If so, use the `uuid` data type. Whether you adopt my design of keep your old. At least switch to the `uuid` data type for a big overall gain in every aspect:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

Comment: FEHLER: Unique Index „de_tt_priceinfo_station_id_recieved“ could not be created
SQL Status:23505
Detail:key (station_id, recieved)=(871828b4-37e5-419c-b7a5-cdbe1e1c0148, 2014-06-12 10:36:20+02) is duplicated. (translated msg)

Comment: I will check the original data tomorrow. Maybe this is an conversion error.

Comment: @Benjamin: If the combination `(station_id, received)` is not unique, create a plain index instead. I suspect an error in your data though (which is why the constraint has the additional benefit of disallowing such errors in the future.

Comment: The original data also has the error, but its just one so im gonna delete the one with the lower id :) The Station ID "should" be a UUID but has various lengths. I will try to test if I can convert it to a UUID but i doubt it.