# Efficiently get records with latest timestamp per group

Tags: postgresql, performance, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

I have a table which roughly looks like this

```
uuid uuid, 
id id, 
data text,
last_updated timestamp
```

Each row has an associated unique *uuid*. However, the key of interest is the *id* (indexed). Whenever we do an update, it happens that a row with the same *id* is inserted, the timestamp is the moment of putting it in the database, and it gets its own *uuid*. I would like to retrieve several of these rows in one query, but retrieving only the latest version.

So far I have

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (16638051, 14727883) 
GROUP BY id, uuid;
```

(*id*s are examples). However, I'm curious how to efficiently retrieve only the rows with the latest timestamp in that query?

Or would doing a single row at a time and retrieving it as a transaction be better?

UPDATE

This seems to do the trick (from [another question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/group-by-one-column-while-sorting-by-another-in-postgresql?rq=1)).

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) *
   FROM   table
   WHERE  id IN (14727883, 16638051) 
   ORDER  BY id, last_updated DESC NULLS LAST
   ) sub
ORDER BY last_updated DESC NULLS LAST
```

However, I wonder if a materialized view wouldn't be easier. It's a read heavy & low write database with a couple million rows, with the updates only happening daily.

Comment: If your workload is read-biased, as you say, and especially if you most often are interested in the latest record for each ID, consider using a "history table" approach: keep only the most recent record in your "main" table and move older records to the history table as new records are inserted. It will affect write performance, of course, but it sounds like in your case it may be an acceptable price to pay for efficient reads.