# PostgreSQL: hstore trgm search on fixed key

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, hstore

I have a table of products with custom properties for each product. So I have `props::hstore` column in my table. I want the user to be able to search products by key/value by first selecting the key and then entering the value with autocomplete feature. So I need two steps here:

1. Get all the keys in `props` field. `SELECT DISTINCT` with `skeys` should work here, but I don't understand how to create index.
2. Find most relavent values for fixed key (autocomplete feature). But seems like gin_trgm_ops can create index only on `value` not on `value` for fixed keys.

Also, maybe it can be a good idea to change the `hstore` with `jsonb`, but I don't see why it can be more perfomant.

Comment: There may be a way after all. How many rows? How many distinct keys total? How many distinct combinations of keys? Your version of Postgres?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter around 10kk of rows, 10-20 distinct keys, around 1000 combinations. It's 9.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performant way to get all distinct names of keys used in an entire hstore (or jsonb) column for a table with many rows.  You could used a materialized view if the list of distinct keys does not have to be perfectly up to date.  But more likely, you should store your key-value pairs in a real relational table rather than in denormalized form.

Answer (score 2):

With only 10-20 distinct keys, I would *urgently* consider one separate column per key in the same row. Unused keys stay NULL. Related case:

- [JSONB vs BRIN Index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/229333/jsonb-vs-brin-index/229370#229370)

That said, **there *is* a way** to get the list of distinct key names from a document type column like `jsonb` or `hstore` comparatively quickly:

Create a btree expression index on the sorted array of key names (or a concatenated string), traverse it with a recursive CTE to emulate a loose index scan and condense the distinct set of keys from the distinct set of *combinations of keys*.

That will read 1000 index tuples for `1000 combinations` (ideally in an index-only scan) instead of all `10kk of rows`. A difference of **factor 10k**.

You need an `IMMUTABLE` function extracting the array or list of keys for the index - like `akeys()` for `hstore`.

A btree index on an array is rarely useful. This is the rare case.

Related code examples:

- [GROUP BY one column, while sorting by another in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74773/group-by-one-column-while-sorting-by-another-in-postgresql/74811#74811)

Comment: I'll add code for an implementation when I find time.

Comment: I've made several perfomance measures and use now id, key, value table with props::int[]. However will check your option as well, thanks.

Comment: @Ximik: If you can provide a minimum demo setup for your current implementation in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), I can demonstrate my idea on this base - when I get around to it.