# JSONB vs BRIN Index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

The requirements go like this:

- Each user has a wallet that can contain tens to a hundred or so different
  currencies, and for each currency an amount
- Number of currency can grow > 1600 (make me anxious about column limit)
- User base in the millions
- A lot of reads for the whole wallet, a bit of write for a currency's amount
- Nightly sum of total amount from all users for each currency

So far I am thinking of 2 options:

- Each user has a `{"currency":amount}` JSONB field, or
- A 500M+ rows table with `user_id`, `currency_id`, `amount`, clustered and use BRIN index on `user_id`

Which way should I go? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: What about testing both ideas?

Comment: You may think about a 3rd option which is using custom data type.

Comment: How many distinct currencies overall? Is the set of currencies stable or changing? Theoretical maximum amount? Fractional digits?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter sorry for the unclarity, the set of currencies will grow. I understand that postgres can only have 16xx fields which can (and will) be a problem. As for type, integer is enough.

Comment: @SahapAsci Thanks for the idea. I have no experience with that, what kind of type will you suggest us to look into in this case?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I will certainly do that too, though a theoretical standpoint certainly helps greatly

Comment: @DennisLau [Composite Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) is related section.

Comment: You will probably have trouble keeping the table clustered well enough, in the face of updates, for BRIN to be useful.  I'd probably go with the long skinny table, but with either a BTREE index (more flexible) or a GIN index (more compact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a mostly immutable set ~ 100 currencies overall (you haven't been clear on that), and your given requirements, consider the simple approach: 1 table with 1 row per user and 1 column per currency. Like:

```
CREATE TABLE wallet (
   user_id   integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY 
 , currency1 integer -- or numeric, depends on missing info
 , currency2 integer
 , ...
 , currency100 integer
);
```

This has a *massively* smaller disk footprint than either of your two options so far.

4 bytes per currency in use (with `integer`), plus 16 bytes for the NULL bitmap. NULL storage is very cheap. See:

- [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147130/939860)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Data type `integer` or `numeric`?

- [PostgreSQL: Which Datatype should be used for Currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15726535/939860)

Your option 1 (`jsonb`) at least doubles the size per currency in use by storing a key name for every amount. Wins with only very few currencies per user, storage-wise. Sums, calculations, indexing are slower and more complicated. Data integrity is hard to enforce.

Your option 2 occupies ~ 44 bytes per currency (separate row). Very clean data model, flexible for adding / removing currencies on the fly, but wastes a lot of space, which makes everything slow.

---

- A *lot of reads for the whole wallet* are as simple as:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM wallet WHERE user_id = 123;
  ```

  You only need an index on `user_id`, which is provided by the PK.
- Getting the *nightly sum of total amount from all users for each currency* is as simple and as fast as can be:

  ```
  SELECT sum(currency1), sum(currency2), ... FROM wallet;
  ```

  No index for that.

---

**If** you have a couple of dozen currencies covering the lion's share of all entries, you could try a **combined strategy**: fixed columns for the regulars and a jsonb column for the rest. This combines minimum storage size with absolute flexibility - at the cost of **more complicated queries and computations**, as you have to combine both now. And much **weaker means to enforce integrity**.

```
CREATE TABLE wallet (
   user_id   integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY 
 , currency1 integer -- or numeric, depends on missing info
 , currency2 integer
 , ...
 , currency70 integer
 , chickenfeed jsonb
);
```

I chose 70 currency columns to stay below the local optimum of 72 columns, before another 8 bytes are allocated for the NULL bitmap. A minor consideration. Chose a number that fits your data distribution.

Maintain a table of all allowed currencies - you do not want to search millions of rows to get the complete list. And use minimum-length key names in the `jsonb` column, like `'{"A1":123}'` (2 bytes for the key) so not to waste GB of storage to repeating lengthy names over and over.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry I wasn't clear on that but yes, the number of currency can grow > 1600 and hit the column limit of postgres as per requirement which is why we can't go the obvious route

Comment: Much more than 100 columns would already be stretching it. I wouldn't go anywhere near the theoretical maximum of columns. I added a possible compromise above.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter what about this idea: the common junction table `(user_id, currency_code, amount)` with PK on `(user_id, currency_code)` and another index on `(currency_code) INCLUDE (amount)` for the daily sums?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: clean and simple - basically the OP's option 2 with an optimized index. (While computing all sums the index won't be of help, though.) The only (considerable) downside: it occupies multiple times the storage which is a drag on performance as well - like discussed above.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks for the help! Can I get you a beer via PayPal or something

Comment: @DennisLau: No PayPal. Good fortune with your project!