# Sqlite: strange behavor on index , about group by operation

Tags: sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE [newtable](
  [id], 
  [HLevel], 
  [LeftBower], 
  [RightBower], 
  [NodeNumber], 
  [NodeCount], 
  [SortPath], 
  [ID:1] INT, 
  [parent] INT, 
  [name] TEXT, 
  [folder] NUM, 
  [size] INT);

CREATE TABLE [tally]([N]);
```

### This is the index I used:
[image]

```
explain query plan select pid ,newtable.size from (
select id as pid, leftbower as lft, rightbower as rgt from newtable where parent =1 and folder = 1
)
as base join newtable on newtable.id> base.lft and newtable.id<base.rgt

output:
id  parent  notused detail
5   0   0   SEARCH TABLE newtable USING INDEX vdsew (folder=?)
12  0   0   SEARCH TABLE newtable USING INDEX dd (id>? AND id<?)
```

but with group by:

```
explain query plan select pid ,newtable.size from (
select id as pid, leftbower as lft, rightbower as rgt from newtable where parent =1 and folder = 1
)
as base join newtable on newtable.id> base.lft and newtable.id<base.rgt group by pid;

output:
id  parent  notused detail
8   0   0   SCAN TABLE newtable
10  0   0   SEARCH TABLE newtable USING INDEX vdsew (folder=?)
23  0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

As rediculous consequence, If I want to get the group by result, create a temp table to save the result, then select from temp group by. This 2-step takes only about 200ms and the combination takes much much longer, depending on what index I am using. For instance, in this case(the indices I posted here).

This query:

```
create table temp as select pid ,newtable.size from (
select id as pid, leftbower as lft, rightbower as rgt from newtable where parent =1 and folder = 1
)

as base join newtable on newtable.id> base.lft and newtable.id<base.rgt ;
select pid, sum(size) from temp group by pid;
```

takes only 250ms to get the result, while

```
select pid ,sum(size) from (
select id as pid, leftbower as lft, rightbower as rgt from newtable where parent =1 and folder = 1
)

as base join newtable on newtable.id> base.lft and newtable.id<base.rgt 
group by pid
```

takes very very long time, depends on which Index I used, and got the same out. In this case, it freezes forever.(It is because it use folder index. After I delete folder index, the query will use parent index and the time is about 14seconds. Anyway, this is another question. Let's focus why the behavoir of using indecies by  group by operation is so strange first.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because your index doesn't include the `size` field so it doesn't cover it so when aggregating over `size` with a `GROUP BY` the operation cost determined by the query optimizer thinks using a `TEMP B-TREE` is the better choice. See the [Temporary Sorting B-Trees](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) section of the "EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN" doc.

You can create an index on `newtable` that includes the `size` field as well and re-check the `EXPLAIN`. More information on a similar issue in this [DBA.StackExchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72381/150011).

Comment: If we simplify this behavior to a model, it is just like that, a=1+1; b=a^5 cost 2 seconds,while b=(1+1)^5 cost 20seconds. First of all, this is rediculous that the separated operation is far more efficient than the combined. If using a temp table for transition is far far better than using a temp b-tree, there must be some bug inside.. SQLite should really abondan this stupid behavior, isn't it? Not to mention that even building a index doesn't need so long. SQLite why not build a temporary index for sorting since it's "temp b-tree" is excessively inefficient?